# Missing PHP extensions in local windows 10 Magento Installation

Tags: php, installation, windows-10, magento2

I'm trying install Apache + PHP + Magento2.1 + MySQL in Windows 10.

I've already installed:

```
      Magento-CE-2.1.8_sample_data
              Content saved in C\Apache24\htdocs
      Apache-2.4.27-Win64-VC15.zip
              Directory: C\Apache24
      PHP Version 5.6.31 php-5.6.31-Win32-VC11-x64.zip
              Directory: C:\PHP
       mysql-community-5.7.19 (Msi installer)
```

In the setup installation (Readiness Check) the follow errors are showed:

```
              PHP Extension curl.
              PHP Extension xsl.
              PHP Extension intl.
              PHP Extension mbstring.
              PHP Extension openssl.
              PHP Extension gd.
```

I've already uncomment this extensions in php.ini
I've copied icud?57.dll files in apache root dir.
Can anyone tell me, What can be happening? Thanks!

The PHP modules loaded are:

```
C:\>cd php
C:\php>php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib
[Zend Modules]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Versions from 5.6.0 to 5.6.4  are not supported. Only php 5 supported are from 5.6.5 and above.

I'd better suggest using php 7 to have better support also for your extensions

Check it better [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

Otherwise, check better for the PHP modules you are enabling. 
According to this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48834/install-magento-2-on-localhost-of-wamp-at-window-system) you have to make sure that all the subsequent modules are enabled, and some are missing in your list.

```
PDO/MySQL
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash, 
simplexml, 
curl, 
gd2, 
ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both 
soap and
add xdebug.max_nesting_level=50000; at php.ini
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. i've Checking the page http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html and i see that the version 5.6.5–5.6.x is compatible with magento 2.18.

Comment: sorry my mistake, but your version is not supported. Check better, versions from 5.6.0 to 5.0.4 are NOT supported, hence yours, 5.6.31 is not suppported.

Comment: I also tried with PHP Version 7.0.23 and get the same error.

Comment: Exactly the same error? seems strange... maybe some bad formatted path? permission issues?

Comment: Check it here in this question  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48834/install-magento-2-on-localhost-of-wamp-at-window-system, they suggest to enable other php extensions that i do not see listed between yours. Maybe it's one of those

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'm not sure why the lines that refer to these extensions were still commented on!!!

Comment: Welcome. I will edit the answer, reporting the correct one here, in order not to leave broken links for future reports. Glad to help.